# Как получить информацию о количестве выделенных страниц процесса?

Tags: objective-c, macos

```
typedef struct kinfo_proc kinfo_proc;

static int GetBSDProcessList(kinfo_proc **processList, size_t 
*processCount) {
kinfo_proc *buffer = NULL;
size_t length;
int sysctlResult;
bool isDone = false;
static const int name[] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0};

assert(processList != NULL);
assert(*processList == NULL);
assert(processCount != NULL);

*processCount = 0;

do {
    assert(buffer == NULL);

    // Вызываем sysctl со значением буфера NULL
    length = 0;
    sysctlResult = sysctl((int *)name, (sizeof(name) / sizeof(*name)) - 1, NULL, &length, NULL, 0);
    if (sysctlResult == -1) {
        sysctlResult = errno;
    }

    // Выделение буфера соответствующего размера на основе результатов из предыдущего вызова
    if (sysctlResult == 0) {
        buffer = malloc(length);
        if (buffer == NULL) {
            sysctlResult = ENOMEM;
        }
    }

    // Вызываем sysctl с новым буфером.
    // Если получим ошибку ENOMEM, надо обнулить буфер и повторить все снова
    if (sysctlResult == 0) {
        sysctlResult = sysctl((int *) name, (sizeof(name) / sizeof(*name)) - 1, buffer, &length, NULL, 0);
        if (sysctlResult == -1) {
            sysctlResult = errno;
        }
        if (sysctlResult == 0) {
            isDone = true;
        } else if (sysctlResult == ENOMEM) {
            assert(buffer != NULL);
            free(buffer);
            buffer = NULL;
            sysctlResult = 0;
        }
    }
} while (sysctlResult == 0 && !isDone);

// Обнуление буфера
if (sysctlResult != 0 && buffer != NULL) {
    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;
}

*processList = buffer;
if (sysctlResult == 0) {
    *processCount = length / sizeof(kinfo_proc);
}

assert((sysctlResult == 0) == (*processList != NULL));

return sysctlResult;
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    kinfo_proc *allProcesses = 0;
    size_t numberOfProcesses;

    GetBSDProcessList(&allProcesses, &numberOfProcesses);

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfProcesses; i++ ) {
        NSLog(@"%d: %sn", allProcesses[i].kp_proc.p_pid, allProcesses[i].kp_proc.p_comm);
        char pathBuffer[PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE];
    }

    free(allProcesses);

}

return 0;
}
```

Есть такой код, как помимо самого процесса вывести количество выделенных страниц этого процесса?